# Dockerfile Case Sensitive Name Issue

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have two machines running Windows 10. Both machines have the same version of docker (19.03.13). On one machine, when running a docker build command, the filename of the docker file must match the casing used for the filename on disk. i.e. if the name of the file is Dockerfile, the -f option of the docker build command must be Dockerfile. On the other machine, the filename passed to the -f option can be dockerfile or Dockerfile. What could explain the difference in behavior when the versions of docker are the same? The only major difference between the two is the specific version of Windows 10 that is installed. The one that doesn't care about the dockerfile casing is using a newer version of Windows 10 than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause of my problem. I happened to compare the advanced docker settings on each machine and noted that the machine that required the correct casing of the docker filename had the following setting that was not set on the other machine.

```json
"features": {
  "buildkit": true
}
```

Once I removed this setting, I was able to build my docker image from Visual Studio which always uses the filename `dockerfile` even though the actual docker file is named `Dockerfile`

Comment: Where do you find these settings?

Comment: @GreenAsJade Currently, I don't have docker for windows installed, so this setting may have moved or not be available any more. AFAIR, there was a text box somewhere in the UI that was labelled 'advanced docker settings'

Comment: I found it in docker settings (cog) Docker Engine.